# Fatal Error: Call to member function on a non-object Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I followed the documentation on Models and I keep getting this error, any help would be appreciated.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

**Message: Undefined property: Manage::$File**

Filename: files/manage.php

Line Number: 14

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_files() on a non-object in /var/www/uisimulator/application/controllers/files/manage.php on line 14*

**Here is my Model: - Located: application/models/files/file.php**

```
class File extends CI_Model {

    var $filename = '';

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // Return all config files
    function get_files() {
        $query = $this->db->get('config_files');
        return $query->result();
    }

    function insert_file(&#41; {
        $this->filename = $this->input->post('filename');
        $this->db->insert('config_files', $this);
    }

    function update_file(&#41; {
        $this->filename = $this->input->post('filename');
        $this->db->update('config_files', $this, array('id' => $this->input->post('id'));
    }
}
```

**Here is my Controller: Location: application/controllers/files/manage.php**

class Manage extends CI_Controller {

```
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('files/file', TRUE);

        $config_files['query'] = $this->File->get_files();

        // Load the head section
        $this->load->view('head');

        // Load the view, passing in the data
        $this->load->view('files/index', $configFiles);

        // Load Footer
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

**Inside my view I have a simple loop to show the results:**

```
  <?php foreach ($configFiles as $file) : ?>
        <li><?php echo $file['filename'];?></li>
   <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Where is $this->File set? I can't see it being set anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 $this->load->model('files/file','', TRUE);
```

EDITED:

```
$data['configFiles'] = $this->File->get_files();
// Load the head section
$this->load->view('head');

// Load the view, passing in the data
$this->load->view('files/index', $data);
```

Comment: That got me to another error and past the last one. A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: configFiles
Filename: files/manage.php
Line Number: 20

Comment: It looks like my variable is undefined?

Comment: // Get config files from model            
            $config_files['query'] = $this->file->get_files();

Answer (score 1):

This code result one record, but give me only fields from one table.

```
function listar_dados_produto($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$id);     
    $query = $this->db->get('produtos');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Note: I am using activerecord. The table produtos return their fields corectly, but i need one field
for another table named categorias.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you have passed `TRUE` as the second parameter in the `$this->load->model` method?

My understanding with CI is that the second parameter is to refer to your model by a different name, other than it's class.

It would appear you are naming your class a boolean, which is bound to cause some kind of error.

Try:

```
$this->load->model('files/file', NULL, TRUE);

//$data['configFiles'] = $this->File->get_files();
print_r($this->File->get_files());
exit;
// do you get any data?


// Load the head section
$this->load->view('head');

// Load the view, passing in the data
$this->load->view('files/index', $data);
```